# Retrieving HDD ATA properties

Tags: c++, windows, 64-bit

I need to get hard disk drive ATA properties such as:

- interface type (SATA-II) (importantly)
- rotation speed (RPM)
- form-factor
- etc.

I try to use WMI with `"Win32_DiskDrive class"`, but unfortunately it does not provide required information.

Please explain me, what functions I should use to get this information?

Comment: How exactly do you expect Windows to know whether a drive has a 3.5 inch form factor? Even "SATA-II" is a stretch. That's a physical bus detail, and Windows uses the same SATA driver. Plus, for compatibility reasons a SATA-II capable controller can communicate to a SATA-I device, and on the Windows/driver side it's still the same SATA-II controller .

Comment: What did you mean? I only need to get information about HDD interface type, RPM and form-factor. What methods exist? And how AIDA64 got these values in this case?